# Can we get greater than 3TB using Windows 7 Media Center?

Tags: windows-media-center

I have been a Windows7 media center user (with extender) since Windows7 was released.

Windows 7 Media Center requires a "local" drive to be selected for Recorded TV.  Also switching between local drives (for space reasons) causes all kinds of issues related to not deleting shows in a series.  They now sell 3TB drives.  But I understand that Windows7 can not handle more than 2TB drives.  I am confused.

Are there any motherboard/hdd combinations that will allow more than 2TB drives for Recored TV in Windows 7 Media center?   If so, how big can it go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with windows 7 and 2 TB is with MBR drives (2 TB is limit for MBR drives). If you have correct computer and set up your drive to use GPT, you should be fine. The bad side is that you'll need a motherboard which has UEFI accessible and have windows 7 installed in UEFI mode for this to work. So look for motherboards which mention EFI orr UEFI (UEFI is new name for EFI).

Comment: There's no need for UEFI if the disk is only used for data

Answer (score 2):

Most modern motherboards have built-in RAID, or you can add an entry-level RAID card for under $200. That's going to be your best bet for extra space beyond 2TB, since you really don't want to be at the mercy of a single drive failure.

Oh, and Windows 7 can handle drives larger than 2TB, see AndrejaKo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is the RAID I/O card.  Many newest cards have a 4T max per port/disk.  Just pick a 1-4 disk RAID 0/1/5/10 card that is in your budget.  After the reboot Vista and the windows media center will "see" that extra space. I personally use this config with a 32 bit VISTA system.  Works fine for me.